# how can i identify an MS Excel object type?

Tags: delphi, excel, com, automation

I'm using late binding OLE automation to work with Excel.  The problem is that I don't know how to work with the value returned by Selection because I don't know what type it is...

How can I determine what kind of object it has returned to me?  I'd hope for a type name....

Or must I run through a list of values I'm expecting?

Comment: Add the code which you are using to help you.

Comment: i'm trying to access vExcelApp.Selection.Column but it's failing saying that it doesn't support Column when I'm on a picture.  that is, of course, no surprise but i'd like to have a good way to know what kind of object i'm being given.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but in Visual Basic it's ```Debug.Print TypeName(Selection)```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can cast the object to `IDispatch` call the `GetTypeInfo()` method to get a `ITypeInfo` interface and there you can call the `GetDocumentation()` method with `memid=MEMBERID_NIL` to get the name.